# iOS MQTT Client Framework : 'SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h' file not found

Tags: ios, mqtt, ios-mqtt-client-framework

I am trying to add MQTT Client framework to my project by copying source files to project. It gives me `SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h file not found` errors. I tried including socketRocket Library and changing `SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h` to `SRWebSocket.h`then I got errors on following line in `MQTTWebsocketTransport.h` file:

```
urlRequest.SR_SSLPinnedCertificates = self.pinnedCertificates;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created the Bridging header for Objective C  (SocketRocket) framework? Also, what error you are getting?

Comment: I am not using swift so need of Bridging header I think

Answer (score 2):

"SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h file not found" caused by you did "pod install" with incorrect target or maybe you didn't copy "SocketRocket" folder into your project.

Let follow steps again:

1. Download iOS MQTT Client Framework again
2. Open podfile and update it:

> Change target from "MQTTClienttvOS" to "MQTTClientiOS"
>
> Change platform to "ios"

3. Do "pod install".
4. Open workspace and build target "MQTTClientiOS"
5. Copy and import MQTTClient.frameworkd and folder "SocketRocket" into your project.

P/S: If you want to use "MQTTWebsocketTransport" instead, you let set MQTTWebsocketTransport.h into Headers and MQTTWebsocketTransport.m into Compile Sources.